# Inputs for a Perceptron

Tags: input, conv-neural-network, perceptron

Okay folks. Bear with me please. When providing inputs into a perceptron for classification, [X_0, X_1] is representing a data point (x,y) from 2 dimensional space. Correct?

So then, if we input [X_0, X_1, X2], we can say this represents (x,y,z) a data point from 3 dimensional space? Could we even say that these inputs represent inputs represent three different data points from 1 dimensional space?

In addition, if we input four vectors, such as [X_0, X_1, X_2], [X_3, X_4, X_5], [X_6, X_7, X_8], and [X_9, X_10, X_11]. One usage interpretation is to say that we are trying to classify four data points in three dimensional space at one time through our perceptron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the features X_0, X_1 and X_2 are not the same, they define different dimensions since they have different meanings and probably not even the same units.

You can pass as many data points as you want to the perceptron, but the number of features (number of entries of each array) has to be always the same. In your example X_0, X_3, X_6 and X_9 have to be the same feature of different objects, since they are handled from the preceptron in the same way.

Comment: Right, I'm using "X_0, X_1 and X_2" as (x,y,z), a data point from three dimensional space. They represent different features. As I understand, one can use a vector of any length and long as you understand what output you are trying to attain. Which I guess means you can use any combinations of vectors and with different lengths? As long as you understand what output you are trying to achieve? The beholder has discretion, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but the length of the array is defined by the information that is available and independent from the output. So yes every length for an array is possible, but need to be constant for a specific problem. If you train a perceptron or any kind of neural network you usually have a lot of known objects all these objects have the same amount of features. In general you can have as many features as you like (also for output), but typically the number of features should be significant lower than the number of objects, to get good predictions.

Comment: Hmm, I probably should not assume anything since I'm relatively new to neural networks. I think you are saying that all my vectors ought to be of the same length if I'm working from one space, which is what I am doing. Come to think of it that makes perfect sense, and be easier to perceive. Feeding a perceptron vectors of different lengths would imply that I am working with data points from different spaces with different respective dimensions. Lol, yeah, that would be a doozy of a problem to classify if even possible. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Meant to say different number of dimensions, respectively.